# How to Show Revolution Slider on Category Page in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I want to show revolution slider on category page using by "nwdthemes revolution slider".

I am doing this:

```
1) created a category "Men"

2) created a revolutions slider with alias "category_men" and short-code {{revslider alias="category_women"}} using by "nwdthemes revolution slider"

3) In category Custom Design tab, put below code into Custom Layout Update field

<reference name="top.container">
    <block type="nwdrevslider/revslider" name="revslider">
        <action method="setAlias"><alias>category_men</alias></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

But revolution slider is not showing on category page front-end. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to go into the Revslider global settings and set it to load scripts globally for it work on category pages.

Comment: Not clear to me. Can you please add some more details or explanation with your answer?

Answer (score 0):

The code you post looks correct. Try to clear cache in **System > Cache management**. If you are using any 3rd-party cache extensions - clear their cache too.

You can also insert slider instead of category image

1. Check if category has image. If yes - remove it
2. Open "Display Settings" tab and set "Display Mode" to **Products Only**
3. Update xml code to

   ```
   <reference name="content">
       <block type="nwdrevslider/revslider" name="revslider" before="-">
           <action method="setAlias"><alias>ecorecycle</alias></action>
       </block>
   </reference>
   ```

Full article can be found here - https://nwdthemes.com/2015/04/29/slideshow-for-category-page-with-slider-revolution-magento-extension/

Answer (score 0):

please try with below code snippet :

```
   <referenceContainer name="page.top">
      <block class="Nwdthemes\Revslider\Block\Revslider">
          <arguments>
               <argument name="alias" xsi:type="string">category_men</argument>
          </arguments>
      </block>
   </referenceContainer>
```

and don't forget to clear the cache